# Setting independent layout in Navigation drawer home

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have created a working Navigation Drawer with few navigation items(using Fragments) with it.

When the app starts it shows the main activity with blank page because the layout set on main activity consists of only navigation items which appears when screen is swiped.

When the navigation items are clicked they work fine.But when I change something in mainactivity layout file like adding textview and then open any navigation items,then the items open respected fragments but the layout remains of mainactivity consisting of textview and not the fragment layout.

So,how could I add something in Mainactivity layout file without effecting navigation items?

This is my mainactivity layout xml.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/container_body"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
/>


<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="this textview appears in all fragment"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

/>


</LinearLayout>

<fragment
android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
android:name="com.example.FragmentDrawer"
android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

when this textview is used this layout is being shown for each fragment and if this is not used then fragment's layout is used.

Comment: Please insert here your layout xml file.

Comment: @MiroM I have added my mainactivity xml file.